# Working code of controlling Gazebo with Player

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi all,

I understand that most of you are using ROS but I am trying to do some simple joint manipulations using Player. I have been trying to work with the available examples but at the moment I am having a lot of errors. By any chance any one has a working example for Player code with Gazebo.
I am trying to compile the simple.c program. I think the main problem is libgazebo.a and gazebo.h are not getting installed on the system. I will try to upload the exact errors.
Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/476/working-code-of-controlling-gazebo-with-player/) by [mfahad](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/95/mfahad/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 39 on 2012-12-10

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [SL Remy](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/43/sl-remy/) on 2012-12-11**:
I'm not using player, but have in the past.. what examples are you referring to? And what type errors are you receiving? (Could you update your question with this information?)

**Comment by [mfahad](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/95/mfahad/) on 2012-12-11**:
Ok i have added some detail but I will try to add more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Joint control with Player is not implemented yet. The only working components of Player are the position2d, laser, and camera interfaces.

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2012-12-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mfahad](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/95/mfahad/) on 2012-12-11**:
Thanks Nate. Is there any other way to do it through C++ code.

**Comment by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) on 2012-12-12**:
You will have to implement the player interfaces that you want. Download the gazebo source code, and look in the `interfaces/player` subdirectory.

**Comment by [mfahad](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/95/mfahad/) on 2012-12-12**:
Thanks. I will try to do it and post and problems that I find here.

**Comment by [mfahad](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/95/mfahad/) on 2012-12-12**:
I was hoping for something like libgazebo to be working though but let me try.